# publicar solo una carpeta en gitHub en una rama paralela

Tags: git, github, angular5, git-push, github-pages

necesito hacer que en mi rama **master** de git, solo se publique el contenido de una carpeta llamada **dist** en una rama paralela que estoy llamando **SRC**, estoy trabajando con angular 5 y basicamente lo que quiero es que mi proyecto (fuente) este en una pagina y mi ghPage (resultado) en otra rama sin el codigo fuente, ante todo muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero entender lo que pides, quieres que de tu rama SRC solo incluir la rama carpeta dist en master, si es así se me ocurre lo siguiente (es bastante sencillo).

Basta con ir a tu rama SRC, crear una nueva rama para no tocar la que tienes:

```
git checkout -tb SRC-solo-dist
```

Luego borra todas las carpetas que no te sirven, básicamente todo menos "dist", si haces un git status verás que estás marcados todos los archivos como "borrados" esto claramente significa que cuando haga un commit dichos archivos desaparecerán, así que haz el commit:

```
git add . (para agregar todos los cambios)
git commit -m "dejando solo la carpeta dist" (para hacer el commit y dejar un mensaje)
```

Ahora ya tienes una rama como la quieres en master, lo siguiente es reemplazar master por esta rama, ten cuidado igualmente porque este proceso romperá todo lo que tengas en master.

Para terminar solo tienes que hacer un push a master usando la opción -f (--force):

```
git push master -f
```

Espero te funcione.

saludos